# Prevent opening of activity when notification comes, when application is on the background

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I have an application to set status bar notifications. I can set them and when I click my status bar notification it opens the application. The issue is if I press home button,it should send application to the background, when the notification comes application automatically comes to the front.

```
 public void setNotification(String date, String alertText, String alertTitle, String sound,String notificationId,int repeatOption, long eventsJni) {
    alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent("sprat.notifier.run");

    intent.putExtra("alertText", alertText);
    intent.putExtra("alertTitle", alertTitle);
    intent.putExtra("sound", sound);
    int id = (int)Integer.valueOf(notificationId);
    intent.putExtra("notificationId", id);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    long time = getDate(date).getTime();
    if(repeatOption == 1){
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), id, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
    }
```

}

when alarm time comes it sets the notification in another activity.

```
public class Notifications extends Activity {
        private int date;
        private String alertText;
        private String alertTitle;
        private String sound;
        private int id;
        private int repeatOption;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (intent == null){
                finish();
                return;
            }
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
            if(intent.getExtras().getString("notif_id") != null && intent.getExtras().getString("notif_type") != null) {
                mNotificationManager.cancel((int)Integer.valueOf(intent.getExtras().getString("notif_id")));
                Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), A.class);
                i.putExtra("notif_id", intent.getExtras().getString("notif_id"));
                i.putExtra("notif_type", intent.getExtras().getString("notif_type"));
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                return;
            }

            set(intent);            

        }

        private void set(Intent intent){

            alertText = intent.getExtras().getString("alertText");
            alertTitle = intent.getExtras().getString("alertTitle");
            sound = intent.getExtras().getString("sound");
            id = intent.getExtras().getInt("notificationId");

            Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(100);


            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
            int icon = R.drawable.icon;
            CharSequence tickerText = alertTitle;
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence contentTitle = alertTitle;
            CharSequence contentText = alertText;
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SpNotifications.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("notif_id", String.valueOf(id));
            notificationIntent.putExtra("notif_type", "Local");


            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
            notification.defaults  |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.defaults  |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            mNotificationManager.notify(id, notification);

            finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's happening here. If you click on the notification, the app should come to the foreground. When you click Home, the Home screen should appear. The app can't automatically come to the front for a notification.

Check the new Notifications guide in the documentation. In particular, it describes how to handle navigation for apps started from a notification.